Configurable beans autowired fields are not injected in Spring 6 while running Junit tests
I am having a problem to get my Junit tests running which uses the classes that are marked as @Configurable. The Configurable marked beans autowired fields are not injected and remains Null.
I provide the code sample project code which reproduces the issue :
SomeDependency.class
package com.codeslab;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SomeDependency {

    public String doSomethingInSomeDependency() {
        return "doSomethingInSomeDependency";
    }
}

SomeService.class
package com.codeslab;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

@Configurable
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private SomeDependency mSomeDependency;

    public String doSomething() {
        return mSomeDependency.doSomethingInSomeDependency();
    }
}

Test code:
SomeTest-Context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- Enable Spring AspectJ support -->
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <!-- Enable AspectJ auto proxying -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean class="com.codeslab.SomeDependency"/>
</beans>

SomeTest.class
package com.codeslab;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/SomeTest-Context.xml" })
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class SomeTest {
    final SomeService mMyService = new SomeService();

    @Autowired
    private SomeDependency mSomeDependency;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(mSomeDependency);

        final String something = mMyService.doSomething();
        Assertions.assertEquals("doSomethingInSomeDependency", something);
    }
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.codes-lab</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-autoproxy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectjweaver.version>1.9.22.1</aspectjweaver.version>
        <spring.version>6.1.13</spring.version>
        <junit.version>5.10.3</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

I have tried to reproduce the problem with above sample code. I already use the aop:aspectj-autoproxy/ in the context. I tried to follow the
Spring-aop-configurable-testing
But I still get the NPE as :
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.codeslab.SomeDependency.doSomethingInSomeDependency()" because "this.mSomeDependency" is null
at com.codeslab.SomeService.doSomething(SomeService.java:23)
at com.codeslab.SomeTest.test(SomeTest.java:32)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)

Isn't the aop:aspectj-autoproxy/ should be responsible to inject the Somedependency into SomeService, What am i missing or overlooking here?
Edit: I prefer compile-time-weaving.

new SomeService() is executed before Spring has had time to enhanche the object. Create a new instance inside the method instead of the class.

@M.Deinum, As I expected it is still the same problem, I moved the new SomeService() after Assertions.assertNotNull(mSomeDependency);. it still fails with same error.

To start aop:aspectj-autoproxy has nothing to do with this, the spring:configured does. However afaik you need to enable loadtime weaving for this and you have to be very careful if you are loading classes quite early on it might not work, because a class might get loaded before Spring has a change to swap the classloader.

It would be helpful if you could provide your test's full stack trace.
Moreover, please rename the variable to someDependency at all places or use @qualifier to give a name of your choice.
 @Autowired
 private SomeDependency mSomeDependency;

